# Расписать строчку по полочкам Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можете расписать пожалуйста строчку по полочкам?

```
digits = [int(char) for char in s if char.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 5):

1. в `digits` записывается содержимое списка `[int(char) for char in s if char.isdigit()]`.
2. Список генерируется налету с помощью list comprehension, внутри которого записан цикл.
3. `for char in s` идет цикл по каждому символу из строки `s`
4. Если данный `char` -- символ, является числом т.е. выполняется `if char.isdigit()`, где `isdigit()` метод класса строки у `char`.
5. Тогда он добавляется в список, причем приводится к типу `int`, т.е. целочисленному типу.

Пример: `abcde123q -> [1,2,3]`